# How to set approved devices on Google Accounts?

Tags: google-account, security

I have an Android tablet that I have the Gmail app on and am signed into. I also have a desktop computer (Windows 10) and a laptop computer (also, Windows 10) that I frequently check my email on, but not as much anymore as I know use my tablet for most stuff. Whenever I sign into my email on the laptop or desktop I get a notification that tells me that I need to go to a page that looks like this:

[image: account pic]
Then it asks me to tell it if this was me. I always select that it was me because I know it is me.

My problem is that it continues to give me the notification and ask me if this was me every time I sign in on my computer or laptop. Is there a way that I can change it so that it doesn't give me that notification every time as this is anoying, and knows that my laptop and desktop are allowed/okay devices.

Comment: Did you follow those "Review Devices" or "Manage Settings" links?

Comment: I tried both. "Review Devices" showed me more information about the devices and "Manage Settings" gave me options for if I wanted to receive text notifications or email notifications when I log in.

Comment: Sum it up: I haven't found anything yet that has helped/solved my problem.